# Parse txt-file, from string to int/float in Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Currently, I need to parse the string saved in a *rot.txt* file：

```
3 3
-0.0963063 0.994044 -0.0510079 
-0.573321 -0.0135081 0.81922 
0.813651 0.10814 0.571207
```

The first row denotes the dim of a rotation matrix, and the rest is a rotation matrix. 
I tried the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
rotation = np.genfromtxt(f_name, delimiter=" ")
```

Obviously, the first row should be skipped. How can I fix this? THX in advance.

Comment: Is your question really how to read a file into a numpy array rather than what the title says? If that's the case you should edit it and possibly add the numpy tag to the question.

Comment: Why not just `rotation = np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1)` ? (maybe specifying a `dtype=` if required)

Comment: It worked, thank you guy,@JonClements.